# Huge delete on PostgreSQL table : Deleting 99,9% of the rows of the table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in my PostgreSQL database that became huge, filled with a lot of useless rows.
As these useless rows represent 99.9% of my table data (about 3.3M rows), I was wondering if deleting them could have a bad impact on my DB :

I know that this operation could take some time and I will be able to block writes on the table during the maintenance operation
But I was wondering if this huge change in the data could also impact performance after the opertation itself.

I found solutions like creating a new table / using TRUNCATE to drop all lines but as this operation will be specific and one shot, I would like to be able to choose the most adapted solution.

I know that Postgre SQL has a VACUUM mechanism but I'm not a DBA expert : Could anyone please confirm that this delete will not impact my table integrity / data structure and that freed space will be reclaimed if needed for new data ?

*PostgreSQL 11.12, with default settings on AWS RDS. I don't have any index on my table and the criteria for rows deletion will not be based on the PK*

Comment: the create table/truncate/insert part is most likely the fastest approach you can get. Or even create new table, drop the old rename the new.

Comment: Deleting your data  will not negatively impact table not structure, negatively impact  data table integrity (assuming proper FKs defined), if a 'deleted' row violates it Postgres will abort the entire process. That said it is still not a bad idea to take a backup before deleting. Once complete run  `vacuum full analyze`. Then you should be ready to go. BTW: 3.3M rows is not huge, maybe the upper end of small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting rows typically does not shrink a PostgreSQL table, sou you would then have to run `VACUUM (FULL)` to compact it, during which the table is inaccessible.

If you are deleting many rows, both the `DELETE` and the `VACUUM (FULL)` will take a long time, and you would be much better off like this:

- create a new table that is defined like the old one
- `INSERT INTO new_tab SELECT * FROM old_tab WHERE ...` to copy over the rows you want to keep
- drop foreign key constraints that point to the old table
- create all indexes and constraints on the new table
- drop the old table and rename the new one

By planning that carefully, you can get away with a short down time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will write a script to schedule these operations.